# Set Date Format Of TextClock In A Widget Programatically

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, date-format, remoteview

I have to set a `TextClock` to show the time as well as the date in another `TextClock`. I want to be able to enable the user to change the format of the date. Eg. instead of `dd MMMM yyyy` they want: `MMMM dd yyyy` which will show January 01 2013.

I have set up a spinner and array to choose this in a config Activity but want to know how to change the `TextClock` format to as I've mentioned. I have tried `views.set.`... but have found nothing.

Surely there must be a way to change the format like I have in the xml file

```
android:format12Hour="dd MMMM yyyy"
android:format24Hour="dd MMMM yyyy"
```

in the java file..

Comment: the answer I provided works perfectly, please mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Update: 31st Jan 2018:
There is a easier way of setting 24hour form via call to setCharSequence shown in this stackoverflow questions accepted answer:
[Can't call setFormat24Hour of a TextClock in a Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772740/cant-call-setformat24hour-of-a-textclock-in-a-widget)

Old alternative answer:
As the widgets view are accessed programmatically  via the RemoteViews android class and that class doesn't expose the set24hourformat method,you have to work around the issue by creating two XML layouts (one for each format you want to switch between) and then set the XML layout using RemoteViews constructor.

A bit of a pain, but only way with current SDK APIs.

Here's an example that you would put in onUpdate():

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds){
    RemoteViews views = null;
    int layoutID = 0;
    if (TwentyFourHourOn){
        layoutID = R.layout.widget_clock_with_24hour;
    } else {
        layoutID = R.layout.widget_clock_with_12hour;
    }

    // the layoutID that is passed in the constructor of the
    //   RemoteViews object is the layout that will be loaded
    //   when the widget is updated.
    views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), layoutID);

    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], views);
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you say 'class doesn't expose the set24hourformat method' ? it does

Comment: @2cupoftech TextClock exposes the method of set24hourformat(). But RemoteView does not. In android widgets, you have to go via the RemoteView

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

That's what you need to do:

```
remoteView.setCharSequence(R.id.widget_current_date, "setFormat12Hour", datePattern);
```

Comment: I try your above code is still not working textclock shown 24hour format only.

Comment: How to give datepattern into charseq like "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a"

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a [setFormat12Hour(CharSequence)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html#setFormat12Hour%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) Method and 24Hour for a TextClock instance.
The char sequence is just like the one you mention.

Comment: Yes I can use this on a regular Activity, but is there an alternative in a widget?

Comment: This will not work because a RemoteView must be used.  So, we need a RemoteView method to make this possible.  I am having the same problem.