# Can't call setFormat24Hour of a TextClock in a Widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm trying to dynamically update the `format24Hour` of my Widget's TextClock.

To do so I'm using RemoteViews like so:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.clockwidget);
views.setString(R.id.textclock, "setFormat24Hour", formatString24.toString());
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
```

This however causes my Widget to show "Problem loading Widget" and logcat shows

```
 03-31 17:37:19.872: W/AppWidgetHostView(1408): updateAppWidget couldn't find any view, using error view
 03-31 17:37:19.872: W/AppWidgetHostView(1408): android.widget.RemoteViews$ActionException: view: android.widget.TextClock doesn't have method: setFormat24Hour(class java.lang.String)
```

However I'm pretty sure that `android.widget.TextClock` has a method `setFormat24Hour(CharSequence format)` which is marked as `@RemotableViewMethod`.

Is there anything I'm missing? Why isn't this working?

Comment: possibly you'd need to explicitly cast the String to CharSequence? (would be weird, though, as String is a CharSequence, but I don't know how the method matching is done)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to njzk2 I found the solution. It was a rather stupid problem.
I need to call `RemoteViews#setCharSequence` instead of setString and then everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been asked months ago, but your own is answer actually wrong I think.

As stated in the API guides, the only classes allowed on an appwidget are:

```
AnalogClock
Button
Chronometer
ImageButton
ImageView
ProgressBar
TextView
ViewFlipper
ListView
GridView
StackView
AdapterViewFlipper
```

Therefore, you need an alarmManager that updates the widget each second, minute or hour when the screen is on, depending on what you want.

When updating the widget you must then change the text of a textview to the actual time. You can format this time as follows:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), viewID);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat timeFormat24 = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
String time24 = timeFormat24.format(c.getTime());
views.setTextViewText(R.id.textClock, time24);
```

[See this link for more information on the formatting.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: While you are correct that the documentation does not List TextClock ( http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html ) as a possible widget inside an app widget it is indeed possible.
This can be verified by either trying it or verifying that the @RemoteView annotation is present in http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/widget/TextClock.java?av=f .

Comment: @PatrickHuy wow... that's amazing! Do you have any information regarding the battery usage of a TextClock? Does is wake the phone when in an AppWidget?

Comment: I don't have hard numbers but the battery usage is better than if you'd manually update a textfield as you don't need a service running. The TextClock listens for a ACTION_TIME_TICK intent. A normal app widget can not do this correctly. The ACTION_TIME_TICK does not wake the phone (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274583/will-time-tick-broadcast-in-deep-sleep ) I have created this app using a TextClock: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cc.frz.circleclock however it also uses a service to update the graphics which is not great for the battery but probably ok.

Comment: @PatrickHuy Thank you very much for this useful help! I included two textclocks (one for the time, one for the date) in my widget and have it placed in my homescreen since about 24 hours.. It is not even showing in the battery stats of my phone settings which is enough for me to accept it as a full success! Again, thanks a lot!